# Excel - Assigning unique numbers based on last value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I mail uniquely numbered tags out to customers.  I also have to keep a record of how many tags, and what number tags were assigned to each customer.  In excel, I have been manually entering the number of tags, then manually entering the tag numbers they are subsequently assigned.  Is there a way to automate the 'tag numbers' when I enter the 'number of tags' into excel.   AKA - once I key a customer is supposed to receive 10 tags, the formula would take into consideration the last tag number assigned was number 120, and then assign this customer tags 121-130?  It would make my life easier if so....    Thanks -

Comment: How's your data laid out? I think you could use `MAX()` to get the last largest number, then go from there? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean exactly. But to get a unique tag you could use `=TEXT(ROW(A1),"format you want your tag in")` should do it.... ie if you use `=TEXT(ROW(A1),"000-000")` the output will be 000-001 etc etc counting up based on previous row.

Answer (score 0):

This is just and example.  Say our worksheet is like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub justin()
    Dim N As Long, j1 As String, nItems As Long
    Dim j2 As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(N + 1, 1) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter new customer name", Type:=2)
    nItems = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter number of tags", Type:=1)

    j1 = CLng(Split(Cells(N, 2).Value, "-")(1)) + 1
    j2 = j1 + nItems - 1
    Cells(N + 1, 2).Value = j1 & "-" & j2
End Sub
```

will allow new entries to be made at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0):

My Dear,

Let this be the Labels for Columns :

A          B            C        D          E             F

Sr.    Customer        Tags     T1         T2         Tag Nos.

1        A             5        1          5           1 ---  5

Please enter first two rows as above ( Say )

Now in  A3  Enter the Formula :  A3 = A2 + 1;  Copy it down the Rows

Now in  B3 Write Customer B , Say you Want 12 Tags For Him so Enter 12 in C3

Now In D3, F3 and E3  Enter the following Formulae :

D3 = E2 +1
E3 = C3 + D3 -1
F3 = D3&"---"&E3     ( Concatenation Can be done using & Also )

Now Copy All these 3 Formulae Down the Rows.

So Now Data Entry Would be Only in :
Column B (For Customer ) and Column C ( For Tags )

Rest of the values would be assigned by the formula.

You can also use Sum formula for Column C For Total Tags assigned so far and cross check with the last number of the Tags.

Thanks.

I got pleasure to solve this.

With Regards.

Harshad Vegda

Comment: I had enter spaces so as to make it clear about Columns, Headings, Values etc for first three rows : Sr. Customer Tags T1 T2 Tag Nos.

1 A 5 1 5 1 --- 5